# rollupjs separate parent and child file

Tags: rollup, rollupjs

Is it possible to separate my parent and child code into two files while compiling using rollup?

Let's say I have a folder called base, it contains all the parent code where the other folder files will extend from.

I would love to separate the parent codes into one file, with the other child files that extend from the parent in other folder into another output file.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an array or an object for the `input` option and rollup will generate a chunk for each entry:

```js
//...
input: {
  parent: 'src/base/parent.js',
  child: 'src/child.js'
}
// or
input: ['src/base/parent.js', 'src/child.js']
```

And you can also use the `manualChunks` option: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#manualchunks

```js
// put everything from base directory into the parent chunk
manualChunks(id) {
  if (id.includes('base')) {
    return 'parent';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. it helped to split the file, It seems that I can not use iife format, so I tried to change to cjs format, I add the following but it doesn't seem to work

const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');

resolve(),
commonjs()

it seems to compile without error but on the browser it keeps saying require is not defined what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Commonjs is the node.js module format, you cannot use it in the browser. On the other hand iife does not support code splitting, that is, loading chunks on demand. Your options are AMD, ES or System. I''m currently using System since it emulates native modules behaviour while being compatible with most browsers https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#bundling-workflow

Comment: Thank you I ended using module format, anyway is there a way to include all files even those that are not called into the bundle? I turned off treeShaking but it's still not including some of the files. Can I also preserve the name of my functions?currently it's calling my function with other name like this: M as Main2, a as Main3. can Main2 just be Main2 without being changed to M?

Comment: Hi, I think you misunderstood what Rollup is for, in general you would use es module syntax for writing your app or library and then distribute a bundled version using Rollup. You should not care about the contents or naming of variables inside the bundle since rollup handles that for you. Take a look at https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-app  and https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-lib . You may open another question explaining what you are really trying to accomplish so I can better understand your use case.